# How do I correct my web app splash screen code to show splash screen first and then move to the main activity?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am trying to implement a `SplashScreen` for my android webapp. However, when I run the app, the `SplashScreen` rather comes after the `MainActivity` screen which is the reverse of what I want to accomplish. I have researched a couple of times on Youtube and Stackoverflow, but it seems most of the questions I came across are peculiar to individuals. This is my code below. Please need help to fix it.

**My Manifest File**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.in10me.jeremy.in10me">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        android:hardwareAccelerated = "true"
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.in10me.HomeActivity"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**My MainActivity File**

```
    package com.in10me.jeremy.in10me;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    import com.in10me.HomeActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        //splash screen time out
        private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;

        WebView myWebview;
        SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(homeIntent);
                    finish();
                }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

            swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
            swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    LoadWeb();
                }
            });

            LoadWeb();

        }

        public void LoadWeb() {

            myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebview.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebview.setFocusable(true);
            myWebview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            myWebview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

            //Improve app intern loading response time performance
            myWebview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            myWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
            myWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            myWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
            webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
            webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

            //Webview here
            myWebview.loadUrl("http://in10me.com");
            swipe.setRefreshing(true);
            myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    myWebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                    //Hide Swipe
                    swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });

            }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed(){
            if (myWebview.canGoBack()) {
                myWebview.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: right now its not waiting for webview to finish the loading it's just getting to home.

Answer (score 1):

A better, speeder and less annoying method would be the following structure:

1. Make your splash screen a HTML file (placed in your assets folder in the App) and load with `myWebview.loadURL()` (very fast to load)
2. At the bottom of the splash screen HTML, add a Javascript redirect to default loading URL (appears to be `http://in10me.com/`).

Advantages of this are huge! The user only waits until the connection is made no matter how slow or quick it takes.

Removes the pointless 4 second timeout.

Initial load time for the splash screen is very quick.

The splash screen will hang around until the real URL is pretty much ready to be rendered, which looks and works better.

A lot less code too :]

Comment: Brilliant approach! Thanks a lot. I will try it asap and give feedback. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should start handler after web page load finish, then it will wait for schedules timeout to display web page and then navigate to HomeActivity.

```
 myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                myWebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                //Hide Swipe
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                         Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                         startActivity(homeIntent);
                         finish();
                }
          }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
     });
}
```